# Cannot inject TimerService

Tags: timer, jboss, ejb

I have an application in JBoss AS 7.1.1 and would like to use the TimerService. I inject it thusly:

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;
```

This results in the following error when accessing a page in the application:

```
16:08:30,471 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/c3e].[Faces Servlet]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/myapp.mypackage.MyClass/timerService -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.myapp.myapp.env."com.dpdhl.cac.c3e.etl.beans.Resources".timerService
```

I have tried several other methods, including injecting the SessionContext or using lookup() on an InitialContext to obtain the SessionContext, but they all run into essentially the same problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what kind of application are you deploying? (ear /war) and what is the fully qualified class name of TimerService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: the bean into which I inject TimerService must be an EJB, not just a CDI bean as it was. I added

```
@Singleton
```

to the bean's declaration and it works now.